# uncheck qcheckbox in qbuttongroip

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt4

Faced such an interesting situation. I have QButtonGroup in which I have a few QCheckBoxes. All QCheckBoxes mutually exclusive as I wanted, however there is one unpleasant fact. When I want to uncheck the selected QCheckBox, I can't do it. How can one get around this problem, can someone come across something similar?

Here my QButtonGroup:

```
self.group = QtGui.QButtonGroup()
self.group.addButton(self.chk_box_1, 1)
self.group.addButton(self.chk_box_2, 2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish the task if you temporarily deactivate the exclusivity property, for your case would be to create a variable that saves the last button pressed and check if it is pressed again, if this happens we deactivate that property by unchecking the button and activating the exclusivity property again.

```
    [...]
    self.group.setExclusive(True)
    self.btnLastChecked = None
    group.buttonClicked.connect(self.onButtonClicked)

def onButtonClicked(self, btn):
    if not self.btnLastChecked:
        self.btnLastChecked = btn
    else:
        if self.btnLastChecked == btn:
            self.sender().setExclusive(False)
            btn.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Unchecked)
            self.sender().setExclusive(True)
            self.btnLastChecked = None
        else:
            self.btnLastChecked = btn
```

**Example:**

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class Widget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        layout=QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self)

        self.group=QtGui.QButtonGroup(self)
        for i in range(10):
            btn = QtGui.QCheckBox(str(i))
            self.group.addButton(btn, i)
            layout.addWidget(btn)

        self.group.setExclusive(True)
        self.btnLastChecked = None
        self.group.buttonClicked.connect(self.onButtonClicked)

    def onButtonClicked(self, btn):
        if not self.btnLastChecked:
            self.btnLastChecked = btn
        else:
            if self.btnLastChecked == btn:
                self.sender().setExclusive(False)
                btn.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Unchecked)
                self.sender().setExclusive(True)
                self.btnLastChecked = None
            else:
                self.btnLastChecked = btn


if __name__=='__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```